# Show that requiring Electrostatic potential to be a stationary point of Electrostatic potential energy is equivalent to Laplace's equation.

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, potential-theory, laplacian

Suppose we want to find the electrostatic potential $\phi$(**r**) inside of some volume $V$ with known boundary conditions. The physical field configuration should *minimize* the electrostatic potential energy function, which is defined as

$U[\phi] = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}  \int_v ( \nabla \phi)^2$d **r**

Show that requiring $\phi$ to be a stationary point of $U$ is equivalent to Laplace's equation, $\nabla^2\phi = 0$.

A hint I was given: take a small deformation of $\phi$, that is $\phi + \delta\phi$, such that $\delta\phi$ vanishes on the boundary of V. We must show that $\delta U = U[\phi + \delta\phi] - U[\phi] = 0$, to linear order in $\delta\phi$.

I have tried limits from first principles and first order taylor expansions. I always seem to just move in a loop however, constantly reaching no conclusion. If anyone is able to show me how this can be done, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\verts{\nabla\pars{\phi + \delta\phi}}^{2} - \verts{\nabla\phi}^{2}
&=\pars{\nabla\phi + \nabla\delta\phi}\cdot\pars{\nabla\phi + \nabla\delta\phi}
-\pars{\nabla\phi}^{2}
\\[5mm]&=2\nabla\phi\cdot\nabla\delta\phi + \pars{\nabla\delta\phi}^{2}
\end{align}

> Up to $\ds{\delta\phi^{2}}$, it becomes
>   $\ds{2\nabla\cdot\pars{\delta\phi\nabla\phi} - 2\delta\phi\nabla\cdot\nabla\phi
> =2\nabla\cdot\pars{\delta\phi\,\nabla\phi} - 2\delta\phi\,\nabla^{2}\phi}$

Then,
$$
0=\delta{\rm U}=\int\bracks{2\nabla\cdot\pars{\delta\phi\,\nabla\phi} - 2\delta\phi\,\nabla^{2}\phi}\,\dd{\bf r}
=2\int_{S}\delta\phi\,\nabla\phi\cdot\dd\vec{\rm S}
-2\int\delta\phi\,\nabla^{2}\phi\ \dd{\bf r}
$$

> For 'arbitrary variations' $\ds{\delta\phi}$, it leads to
>   $\ds{\color{#66f}{\large\nabla^{2}\phi = 0}}$ provided
>   $\ds{\int_{S}\delta\phi\,\nabla\phi\cdot\dd\vec{\rm S}}$ vanishes out.